# Windows 10 - Recent Folders, Shell Command Not Working

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm trying to get Recent Folders back in Windows Explorer, I had it running before but lost it in an update :(

The standard first step is to run `shell:::{22877a6d-37a1-461a-91b0-dbda5aaebc99}` either through a run command or entering it in Explorer address bar to access the Recent Files folder.

In both cases,however, I get explorer.exe popup saying "This file does not have an app associated with it for performing this action ...."

What do i need to fix?

Comment: If you go to "View" - "Options" in Explorer, in the "Privacy" section, if you toggle the options does that help?  I.e. disable/enable

Comment: Since this happened after an update, I would try DISM and SFC.  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator. Run: dism.exe //online  /clenaup-image  /restore-health and when that has completed run: SFC /SCANNOW .  When all is done, restart and test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Shell:recent* got me Recent Items but I really wanted Recent Folders and also to show it in Save/Save As dialogs. Eventually I found a regedit file here which solved it all.
[Winhelponline](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/pin-recent-folders-places-navigation-pane-windows-10-file-explorer/)

[rantmode on] Why do MS keep breaking things that are working fine? [rantmode off]

Thanks to those who replied

Answer (score 1):

Follow this [answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/recent-folders-rather-than-frequent-folders-in/171b786e-0521-4aa4-9fcb-7508f0074fe6)

If it doesn't work then

From https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/three-ways-easily-access-your-most-recent-documents-and-files-windows-8x.htm

Method 1: Use the Run Dialog Box

Open the Run Dialog Box with the keyboard shortcut Windows Key+R

Enter shell:recent

This will open the folder listing all of your recent items. The list can be quite long and may contain items that are not as recent, and you may even want to delete some of them.

Note: The contents of the Recent Items folder is different from the contents of the File Explorer entry Recent Places, which contains folders that have been recently visited rather than files. They often have quite different contents.

Method 2: Make a Desktop Shortcut to the Recent Items Folder

If you like (or need) to look at the contents of the Recent Items folder on a frequent basis, you may want to create a shortcut on your desktop:

Right-click on the desktop

In the Context Menu, choose New

Select Shortcut

In the box, “type the location of the item”, enter %AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\

Click Next

Name the shortcut Recent Items or a different name if desired

Click Finish

You can also pin this shortcut to the taskbar or place it in another convenient location.

Method 3: Add Recent Items to the Quick Access Menu

The Quick Access Menu (also called the Power User’s Menu) is another possible place to add an entry for Recent Items. This is the menu opened by the keyboard shortcut Windows Key+X. Use the path:

%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\

Contrary to what some articles on the Internet say, you cannot simply add shortcuts to the folder that is used by the Quick Access Menu. For security reasons, Windows will not allow additions unless the shortcuts contain certain code. The utility Windows Key+X menu editor takes care of that problem.